# How can I print HTML file to PDF from command line in Windows 10 (without Admin access, and NOT using Chrome)?

Tags: command-line, pdf, printing

I need to generate PDFs from a bunch of HTML files, and I want to do it from a command line rather than by hand. I know how to do it using Chrome but I prefer to avoid it since it seems to cause my computer to freeze after running it a few hundred times.

I don't have Admin rights on this computer so I can't install any new tools.

Is there a way to run a Microsoft or Adobe Print to PDF operation from command line with these constraints? Thx!

UPDATE: FWIW, here's the command I use with Chrome (which causes issues):

```
"c:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe" --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf="out.pdf" "in.html" > /dev/null
```

It looks like a Linux command since I am running it from Cygwin

Comment: @Dave thx but it requires installing PDFcretor on my machine

Comment: Why not use a website to do it then. FTP the files to a server, then point the online PDF creator to it. There are many online PDF creation services for free

Comment: Also, how are you running it? Are you manually typing that string with new paths every single time you want to print to PDF. When it crashes, how many instances of Chrome exist? Maybe you can execute that task in powershell or a bat file and kill the task afterwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe Acrobat cannot print "HTML to PDF" only PDF to anything else.

The Question is based on older issues, which should not be a problem today, as running in MS Windows where MS Edge III+ (Powered by Acrobat) is now the standard not the earlier Internet Explorer, thus needing a problematic chrome solution.

From CMD or a script run 32 bit or add correct location for 64 bit variant
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"`

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --headless --print-to-pdf="c:\outdir\out.pdf" "c:\indir\in.html"
```

**Do not disable GPU and ideally those filenames should be absolute**, and don't send to nul, as you cannot see any problems. If your running large numbers ensure there is time for closure of one cycle before start another so include timeouts as required, otherwise you will probably get overlapping resource demands causing memory creep until failure. Probably causing the OP complaint about lock-up.

So for a loop use cmd `timeout #` to delay each run (Use Task Manager to monitor for overlapping time based resource failures) and also there are switches for HTML.js such as compositor and virtual time budget.

A comprehensive list can be found for chromium here https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ but be-aware MS Edge is currently still using some --headless=old variations.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this qualifies as an answer or a comment, but I'll chance it anyway...

I found this after a brief but not all too fruitful research: https://sourceforge.net/projects/podofo/

From what I understand, a portable PDF printer is hard to come by, because it involves installing drivers, which requires at least a modicum of admin rights.

This *seems to be* the next best thing, as it doesn't require any install.

You could also open your HTML files in OpenOffice/LibreOffice (the portable versions) and use the "Save as PDF" functionality they support natively, but I'm not sure they're the best tool for batch-treatment.

Comment: Trying to build it under cygwin now. Getting `Run cmake on the CMakeLists.txt in the project root, not the one in the 'src' directory` error, not sure why. Going Visual Studio route won't be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a native solution, but it is run from the command line and shouldn't require Admin privilege. It is also precompiled as a binary which might be desirable compared to the other suggestion:

https://wkhtmltopdf.org/

An example of the command you'd run to print Google's HTML page to a PDF:

```
wkhtmltopdf http://google.com google.pdf
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).